# How to fix XSS - Stored vulnerability in java

Tags: xss, jdbctemplate

I have a db call through jdbcTemplate with the input validated with ESAPI valid input functionality.The veracode raises a XSS-stored finding for the same.Can some one please help me how to fix this.

```
obj = jdbcTemplate.query(
                "Select a,b from c where d = ?",
                new Object[] { ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL(sqlCodec, d) }, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(MyObject.class));
```